# Strange Eclipse Error with XML files

Tags: android, eclipse

When i try to view my XML's grahpic layout, Eclipse do strange things:
The buttons above the layouts are vibrating. Everyting become very slow and if i open task killer i see that Eclipse is useing 1.000.000 K memory, yes a million.

Its only happens at xml views, not at java code.

Then everyhing become so slow that i must kill eclipse via task killer.

Any ideas ?

Comment: can u check if you have the latest adt version

Comment: What machine are you working with? And I would advise you to just avoid looking at the graphical layout editor. Just make the edits to the xml code.

Comment: Can I answer my own question ? I turned off android lint and everything is OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn of lint always when this thing happens.

See answer on this topic:
[Eclipse "Java heap space" error, Eclipse not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731436/eclipse-java-heap-space-error-eclipse-not-responding)