# what does Java heap space error means? how can i avoid termination of eclipse?

Tags: android

An error box appear with a message of `java heap space error`.
What does this error means. I cant solve it. It results in not responding the status of eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse.ini settings will take effect only if you change following:

Run -> External Tools -> External Tool

Configurations. go to configuration that u use, under jre tab -select option

Run in same JRE in workspace.

Check
[Error “java heap size” in Eclipse Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393215/error-java-heap-size-in-eclipse-android/15393350#15393350)

Answer (score 0):

I too had a same problem before few week and i tried this solution

Turned off your Lint checking it will stop checking error.

For turning of Lint checking go to

`Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint error checking`

and uncheck this two.

**When saving file, check for errors**, and

**Run full error check.....**

Hope this will help you.

For more reference you can visit [Eclipse "Java heap space" error, Eclipse not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731436/eclipse-java-heap-space-error-eclipse-not-responding)